# Data rate vs. data volume

Tags: communication, data, transmission

I'm a little confused by the two terms. What do data rate and data volume mean and what are the differences?

Comment: Try google - was does it tell you? A little basic research isn't too hard. Google is your friend.

Comment: Data volume = data rate * time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Rate means the amount of Data per time unit. For example 100 Mega Bytes of data per 1 second of time or 800mbps (Mega Bit per second assuming each byte is 8 bits).

Data Volume means total amount of dada. for example 1 DVD can accomodate total of 4 or 8 Giga Byte data.

Answer (score 0):

Data rate is a troughput like a stream of water, the unit is bits per seconds, Kbps, Mbps, Gbps... with a lower case b

A volume is more like a stock, a pool or lake full of water. Unit is byte (8 bits) KB, MB, GB... with an uppercase B